# Track specific data of an in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I want to trak below user activity of my in-house app. How can i achieve these? Checked google analytics but it doesn't provide what i am looking for.
- User name
- Version of app
- Date & Time of Login
- Location (if available)
- IP address

Comment: Please provide more info regarding what, exactly, are you trying to do and what you have already tried.

Comment: Its an in-house app. What the app is providing (user functionality), same sort of things can be done by the website also. So the client wants to know, which employees are using the app, which employees are using the website so that they can have some statistics. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to add this as an answer because it doesn't specifically address your question but I did find this info useful when picking the analytic tool I use.  There are several dozen different types of 3rd-party analytics and this site compares a few of them.  Maybe it can help you, too.  http://www.apptamin.com/blog/app-analytics-tools/

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It really helped